# Is it possible to convert buffredImage to scalable vector image (SVG) using java?

Tags: java, swing, svg, bufferedimage, vector-graphics

Is it possible to convert a BufferedImage to scalable vector graphic (SVG) in java? Is there any java library to do so?
I have found [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) useful for converting SVG files to other formats (for example [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html)) but not the other way around. 
Also in cases of [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) and its java implementation [delineate](http://delineate.sourceforge.net/) i need to install the software, whereas i am looking for a library jar which i can just import and use in my project.

Suggestion for any such library will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Batik will allow you to 'embed' a BufferedImage within an SVG file. Here's [an example](http://osdir.com/ml/batik-users-xmlgraphics.apache.org/2013-08/msg00021.html).

Note that a BufferedImage is already a rastered bitmap, however, and will necessarily [pixelate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixelation) as you resize the SVG image. If you're seeking the benefits of image scaling without pixelation, you'll need to go to the extra effort of "redrawing" the image with the Batik API.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "redrawing the image"?